# getting "BadMethodCallException" while posting an action through test user - facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created my own action on my facebook app and sent for approval. They asked me to re-submit the action after testing my action with 'Auth Dialog Preview User' and ensure that the action appears on it's timeline.

When i try to post an action through facebook's javascript-sdk from the test user, i get an console error as

message: "Call to a member function on a non-object"
type: "BadMethodCallException"

The post is successfull through the admin account. but when i switch the account to the test user, it fails.

Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

think I had the same issue. Got a null response after publishing the action using the test account.

This is because by default, Facebook only allows Basic Information permissions to the App. So OG Actions get rejected.

Try to do this,

1. Login to the test account
2. Go to Settings
3. Go to Apps
4. Remove your app
5. Open your app

that will make it to re-authorize the App and then your App has permission to publish OG actions through the testing account.

100% worked for me :)